# How can I center the react bootstrap modal? "Vertically centered"

Tags: popup, bootstrap-modal, react-modal

I already assigned: aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"   centered but it's not working.

Even this react bootstrap example "Vertically centered" not working.
https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/modal/#rb-docs-content

Answer (score 0):

ARIA stands for Accessible Rich Internet Applications.
It is a set of specific tags where you can define text that would help users with some difficulties to still use your website.
It is for example used for blind people, so an application can read these tags and guide them through the website

In other words : nothing you define under aria-xxx tags is actually changing your website, so I'm 100% sure it's not your issue here. In the sample, the keyword "centered" is probably what centers the element.

Also, don't forget CSS stands for **Cascading** Style Sheet, meaning that the property of the parent will impact the children. If your parent are different, you might have different results than the example you started from